# Problems with reading from files in C++ (ifstream), only works for input size of multiples of x (depending on data type)

Tags: c++, stream, ifstream

I started learning C++ a month ago and stumbled upon something strange:

I try to read data from a file into a vector (or simply write it out with std::cout). However until the file contains a certain amount of data, nothing happens.
In case my file contains only ints the number of Elements until something is read is 1861, where 1860 Elements will be appended to the vector.. 
However this number might vary, depending on your system.

I constructed a minimmum example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{

    std::ofstream out( "newFile" );

    const int NumberElements = 1860;

    for( int index = 0; index != NumberElements; ++index )
    {
        out << index << " ";
    }
    //This sucessfully fills the file up until here


    std::vector<int> readInHere;
    std::ifstream in( "newFile" );

    int temp;
    while ( in >> temp )
    {
        readInHere.push_back( temp );
    }

    std::cout << readInHere.size() << '\n';    //This prints out 0

    return 0;
}
```

I have no idea what's happening here and would really appreciate if you can help me understand it.
I already tried to google it but I'm probably missing the right catchphrase to find anything useful.

Thanks for your Help!

Comment: You should close out before you open the file for reading.  You should also check to make sure you actually opened the file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call [`out.close();`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/close/) to ensure the buffer is flushed and is ok to start reading.

Comment: `out.close()` is done automatically by the destructor.

Comment: @0x499602D2 in this case, the destructor isn't called until after he tries reading from the file he just wrote to.  If he used some scopes here, that would also work, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

You are not closing the file after writting, the `stream` not necessary write the data immediately in the file, it has caching mechanism for performance, to  force saving you need to call ([`out.flush()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/flush) or `out.close()`).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::ofstream out("newFile");

    const int NumberElements = 1860;    
    for (int index = 0; index != NumberElements; ++index) {
        out << index << " ";
    }
    out.close();
    // This sucessfully fills the file up until here

    std::vector<int> readInHere;
    std::ifstream in("newFile");

    int temp;
    while (in >> temp) {
        readInHere.push_back(temp);
    }
    in.close();
    std::cout << readInHere.size() << '\n'; // This prints out 0

    return 0;
}
```